# Android studio - Purpose of Transform API in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Im not clear on what the transform API is used for, from the [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api) it says the following:

> Starting with 1.5.0-beta1, the Gradle plugin includes a Transform API allowing 3rd party plugins to manipulate compiled class files before they are converted to dex files.
>   (The API existed in 1.4.0-beta2 but it's been completely revamped in 1.5.0-beta1)
>
> The goal of this API is to simplify injecting custom class
>   manipulations without having to deal with tasks, and to offer more
>   flexibility on what is manipulated. The internal code processing
>   (jacoco, progard, multi-dex) have all moved to this new mechanism
>   already in 1.5.0-beta1. Note: this applies only to the javac/dx code
>   path. Jack does not use this API at the moment.

Can anyone provide a real world example of when i would use a transform ? When would i want to manipulate a compiled class file before it converts to dex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solid example: [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda).

Android doesn't support Java8, but a lot of people want lambda support anyways. [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) takes compiled classes and makes their lambdas backwards-compatible.

The current stable version of gradle-retrolambda doesn't use the transform API, but I know there's a beta version of it that does.

Comment: out of curiosity could i not use this as a type of aspectJ ? because i could inject code into classes before dex conversion right ?

Comment: With Transform API, you get access to app resources like drawables and layout too